# css transition with pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make my animation start form the center instead of left. I am attaching the code that I have done.

```js
function yScroll() {
    var nav,yPos;
    nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    yPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if(yPos>5) {
        nav.style.width = '100%';
        nav.style.margin = '0';
        nav.style.position = 'fixed';
        nav.style.top = '0';
    }else {
        nav.style.width = '4em';
        nav.style.margin = "8em auto";
        nav.style.position = 'static';
        nav.style.top = 'auto';
    }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll",yScroll);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
}
    
#nav {
    margin: 8em auto;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    background-color: grey;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out, margin 1s ease-in-out;
}
    
section.height {
    height: 100em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
  <head>
    <title>animate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="animate.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="nav">
    </div>
    <section class="height"></section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above is the code I have written for my testing unfortunately its starting from left I want it to go from center to left

Comment: DBS further down the lane i came across another problem related to the earlier problem but did not know how to continue with this so made a different question. if you would be kind enough to check it out i would be very obliged.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the method of centring to use `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` which works correctly for fixed elements (Using margin auto on both sides doesn't work for fixed position elements)

The changes also stay as `fixed` and remove the auto margins.

```js
function yScroll() {
    var nav,yPos;
    nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    yPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if(yPos>5) {
        nav.style.width = '100%';
        nav.style.margin = '0';
        nav.style.top = '0';
        nav.style.borderRadius = "0";
    }else {
        nav.style.width = '4em';
        nav.style.margin = "8em 0";
        nav.style.top = 'auto';
        nav.style.borderRadius = "6px";
    }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll",yScroll);
```

```css
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin: 8em 0;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out, margin 1s ease-in-out;
}
    
section.height {
    height: 100em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
  <head>
    <title>animate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="animate.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="nav">
    </div>
    <section class="height"></section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes this is what i was hoping for. the code works great. can you check out one more thing for me. i was trying to give and remove rounded borders to the #nav but is not working with javascript. appreciate your help man. thanks

Comment: I've added rounded corners in, if this helps you or solves your problem, you can upvote it or accept it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the position setting and when scrolling down, set the margin to "0 auto" instead of "0".

```js
function yScroll() {
    var nav,yPos;
    nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    yPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if(yPos>5) {
        nav.style.width = '100%';
        nav.style.margin = '0 auto';
        nav.style.top = '0';
    }else {
        nav.style.width = '4em';
        nav.style.margin = "8em auto";
        nav.style.top = 'auto';
    }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll",yScroll);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
}
    
#nav {
    margin: 8em auto;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    background-color: grey;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out, margin 1s ease-in-out;
}
    
section.height {
    height: 100em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
  <head>
    <title>animate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="animate.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="nav">
    </div>
    <section class="height"></section>
  </body>
</html>
```